# How to extract XML data that contains namespaces in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

Query:

```
select * from xmltable(XMLNAMESPACES('http://test/asdf/bean' as "bean",  
default 'http://example.org/SCL/CommonTypes') , '/bean:TransactionData/TransactionRequest/CustomerId'  
passing xmltype('<ns:TransactionData xmlns:ns="http://test/asdf/bean" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns:TransactionData">
        <TransactionRequest xmlns:nste="http://pegasus/component/payment/bean" xsi:type="nste:bankTransferRequest">
                <CustomerId>0001</CustomerId>
                <Account>12332131321331</Account>
                <Currency>MMK</Currency>
                <Reference>83550 test</Reference>
        </TransactionRequest>
</ns:TransactionData>'));
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question. E.g. what exactly is not working.

Comment: Remove this `, default 'http://example.org/SCL/CommonTypes'`. It's not required here.

Comment: I have a table in an Oracle 12c Database that contains a XML Type Column like above sample XML.but when I reteive like above query.It can't not return any data and also try like "SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(XMLField), '/ns/:TransactionData/TransactionRequest/Field[@key="CustomerId"]') CustomerId
FROM myTable

Comment: It is also return blank field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t.* from xmltable(XMLNAMESPACES('http://test/asdf/bean' as "ns") 
,'//ns:TransactionData/TransactionRequest/CustomerId'
 passing xmltype('<ns:TransactionData xmlns:ns="http://test/asdf/bean" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns:TransactionData">
        <TransactionRequest xmlns:nste="http://pegasus/component/payment/bean" xsi:type="nste:bankTransferRequest">
                <CustomerId>0001</CustomerId>
                <Account>12332131321331</Account>
                <Currency>MMK</Currency>
                <Reference>83550 test</Reference>
        </TransactionRequest>
</ns:TransactionData>')) as t
```

If you want to use bean as namespace prefix:

```
select t.* from xmltable(XMLNAMESPACES('http://test/asdf/bean' as "bean") 
,'//bean:TransactionData/TransactionRequest/CustomerId'
 passing xmltype('<ns:TransactionData xmlns:ns="http://test/asdf/bean" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns:TransactionData">
        <TransactionRequest xmlns:nste="http://pegasus/component/payment/bean" xsi:type="nste:bankTransferRequest">
                <CustomerId>0001</CustomerId>
                <Account>12332131321331</Account>
                <Currency>MMK</Currency>
                <Reference>83550 test</Reference>
        </TransactionRequest>
</ns:TransactionData>')) as t
```

Example output using Oracle 12.1 and SQLplus.

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select t.* from xmltable(XMLNAMESPACES('http://test/asdf/bean' as "bean")
  2  ,'//bean:TransactionData/TransactionRequest/CustomerId'
  3   passing xmltype('<ns:TransactionData xmlns:ns="http://test/asdf/bean" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns:TransactionData">
  4          <TransactionRequest xmlns:nste="http://pegasus/component/payment/bean" xsi:type="nste:bankTransferRequest">
  5                  <CustomerId>0001</CustomerId>
  6                  <Account>12332131321331</Account>
  7                  <Currency>MMK</Currency>
  8                  <Reference>83550 test</Reference>
  9          </TransactionRequest>
 10  </ns:TransactionData>')) as t;

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<CustomerId>0001</CustomerId>
```

Comment: The `bean` namespace is present in the XML. It has just a different prefix there. Prefixes are not required to match, URIs are. You are right about the default namespace.

Comment: Why would you want to use a different prefix?

Comment: Thanks,I try like your query with bean namespace.but it also nothing result return.please advice me.thanks

Comment: The query as posted, returns CustomerId. What don't you like about it?

Comment: @Rene Why wouldn't you? It makes no difference. The prefix is completely ephemeral. The OP's code is perfectly fine in this regard.

Comment: Trust me that the namespace prefix does not make any difference whatsoever. That's a red herring.

Comment: Added the solution with bean as namespace prefix.

Comment: It's a wide-spread misconception that namespace prefixes have to match between XPath and XML. In other words, the answer is still misleading in the sentence *"Neither of them is present in the XML"*. One of them is clearly present.

Comment: Thanks, removed that as well.

Comment: Already try with your query,but return no data.It show nothing row instead of CusID "0001".I have also try with another way like "SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(TRANSACTIONDATA), '//ns:TransactionData/TransactionRequest/CustomerID', 'xmlns:ns="http://pegasus/component/storeandforward/foundation/bean"') AS Extracted
FROM Mytable".It is also returns blank field instead of CusID "0001".I used oracle 12c and SQL workbench/J.TRANSACTIONDATA is field name of my table.

Comment: @Ye Low. Added output of my SQLplus session to demonstrate that the code works. Please edit your question to show exactly what you are doing.

Comment: SELECT EXTRACTVALUE working fine now.it need to case sensitive. thanks